# Chakra UI is not loading when used with Storybook

Tags: reactjs, button, create-react-app, storybook, chakra-ui

I'm still learning storybook. I've set up Storybook and Chakra-UI using create-react-app following the decorator's documentation as mentioned [here](https://storybook.js.org/docs/react/writing-stories/decorators#global-decorators). Here's the link for the [repository](https://github.com/divyaYK/chakra_storybook).

For some reason, Storybook is not loading the styles from Chakra-UI.
Here's the button on react app:

[image]

Here's the button on Storybook:
[image]

The variants from the custom theme are working but not colours:

[image]

I'm not sure how to correct this problem. Please help me out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be resolved in 1 of 2 ways. For my the old unofficial addon works out of the box.

## Option 1: unofficial addon but simpler

Install
https://storybook.js.org/addons/@snek-at/storybook-addon-chakra-ui

*.storybook/main.js*

```
module.exports = {
  addons: ['@snek-at/storybook-addon-chakra-ui']
}
```

And since you need custom theme:

```
import myTheme from '../theme'
export const parameters = {chakra: {theme: myTheme}}
```

## Option 2: - Official addon

Is to use the very new official chakra-ui addon.

**@chakra-ui/storybook-addon**

```
npm i -D @chakra-ui/storybook-addon
npm i @chakra-ui/icons
```

Then add the addon  in *.storybook/main.js*

```
module.exports = {
  addons: ['@chakra-ui/storybook-addon'],
}
```

*.storybook/preview.js*

```
const theme = require('../path/to/your/theme')

export const parameters = {
  chakra: {
    theme,
  },
}
```

However, this did NOT work out of the box for me. I would wind up with webpack errors on build. To fix this I am using the experimental webpack 5 for storybook.
For step by step instructions on how to install:
https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/blob/next/MIGRATION.md#webpack-5

But for me this was enough

```
npm install @storybook/builder-webpack5 @storybook/manager-webpack5 --save-dev
```

and
*.storybook/main.js*

```
module.exports = {
  core: {
    builder: 'webpack5',
  },
};
```